# Image position in C#

Tags: c#

I can get image properties:

```
imgObj.Width
imgObj.Height
```

But how do I get its top left corner position?

I would imagine something like:

```
imgObj.Xpos
imgObj.Ypos
```

Sorry for too simple question :-)

edit:

WPF, imgObj is some Image I added using Toolbox

Comment: what is `imgObj`?

Comment: Is this WPF? ASP.NET? Windows Forms? What is a imgObj?

Comment: (0,0)  Or do you mean relative to something?

Comment: Perhaps you can try pushing F1 after you have navigated to the classname with F12. You will end up at the mdsn documentation which will help you in the future with these kind of questions.

Comment: well, before asking I searched through this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms610982
But did not find anything about position, so I asked here :-)

Comment: I should have add, that I am total newbie to c sharp, thats why my question was so silly. I have added that its wpf and about image, hope its more accurate now :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `imgObj.Margin.Top` and `imgObj.Margin.Left`

Comment: Thanks, its imgObj.Margin.Top :-)

Answer (score 1):

If it is a Windows Forms application you can get the information like using`imgObj.Location.X` and`imgObj.Location.Y;`.

Comment: I think this is what hes looking for :) +1